# What is the Rust equivalent of Python os.pathsep?

Tags: python, path, rust, environment-variables

Python has:

> **os.pathsep**: 
>   The character conventionally used by the operating system to separate search path components (as in PATH), such as ':' for POSIX or ';' for Windows. Also available via `os.path`.

Is there a similar os-specific definition in Rust?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a constant for this, but Rust does provide [`std:::env::split_paths`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/env/fn.split_paths.html) and [`std::env::join_paths`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/env/fn.join_paths.html).